# How to map multiple records using SqlMap in Ibatis

Tags: java, ibatis

I am just getting into ibatis with SqlMap for the first time and I have run into a problem.  I have figured out how to insert, delete, update, and select single records.  Now however I am trying to write a select statement that will bring back more than a single record and I am getting mapping errors.  How do I specify that the result should be a List of my custom objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've figured it out.  Using java I simply had to use the queryForList function instead of queryForObject.